# How to use 2 arguments in a 1-arg javascript function?

Tags: javascript, closures, nested-function

I am using the http module in node.js to read from url. The http.get function has [this signature](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback):

```
http.get(options[, callback])
```

The callback function takes a single argument, res. What can I do if I want to use extra objects/functions inside the callback? I can think of inlining the get call like so:

```
outerFunction = function(xyz) {
  http.get(options, (res) => {
    // do stuff with xyz here
    xyz(res.blah);
  }
});
```

But if my callback gets long I want to declare it upfront somewhere:

```
myCallback = function(xyz) {
  return function(r) { xyz(r.blah); };
}
```

And invoke myCallback like so:

```
outerFunction = function(xyz) {
  http.get(options, (res) => {
    myCallback(xyz)(res);
  });
}
```

But that seems super clumsy and only to get around the 1-arg callback restriction.

Are there better ways? Thanks!

Comment: Why is `myCallback` returning a function instead of receiving two arguments?

Comment: If you're going to return a function, then you could do this: `http.get(options, myCallback(xyz))`. But if you're just going to invoke `myCallback` inside the arrow function, then it might as well receive both params: `http.get(options, res => myCallback(xyz, res))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code please,because myCallback return a function,then after get the resource,http will pass the res into xyz automatically.

```
outerFunction = function(xyz) {
   http.get(options,myCallback(xyz));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! My brain froze when I posted this question. I had the fuzzy idea that I wanted to form a closure to pass to the second argument of http.get, but messed it up by also _invoking_ the closure by using an arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object.

> The arguments object is a local variable available within all
>   functions. You can refer to a function's arguments within the function
>   by using the arguments object. This object contains an entry for each
>   argument passed to the function, the first entry's index starting at
>   0.

Quick example:

```
function test1234(a){
    var args = arguments;
    console.log(args); // prints -> 0: "a", 1: "b"
}

test1234('a', 'b');
```